# achartengine : Zoom chart Programmatically

Tags: android, achartengine

My App plots Line chart using `achartengine` Library. 
 
The Line chart can be zoomed in and out by setting zoom property using `setZoomEnabled` API, using pinch-to-zoom, and app is NOT using zoom buttons/icons for it.

This zoom functionality works fine when user manually zooms-in and , same when zooms out. Everything just works fine.

But my requirement is to do zoom-in/out through code on specific event.

For instance: in `onResume()` of a `Fragment` , or `onClick` of a Button in UI, I want to restore Zoomed state of Line chart back to Non-zoomed state, through code!

Is there a way or an API in `achartengine` which allows Line chart to zoom-in or zoom-out **PROGRAMMATICALLY**?